# Issue drawing graphics to Bitmap in c#

Tags: c#, windows, graphics, bitmap, draw

I am trying to make a paint program. I have got the basic's working as well as a way to record all mouse clicks so that I can draw them to a bitmap and then save it except it doesn't work, using this method I can redraw the graphics except when I try to save the file the bitmap image is blank?

Heres my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel; 
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
namespace Paint_Program
{
    public partial class PaintImg : Form
    {

    public Boolean veryimportantbool = false;
    int drawcount = 0;
    int brushsize = 16;

    List<Point> pts = new List<Point>();
    Point recordpoint { get; set; }

    public PaintImg()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //Cursor drawCursor = new Cursor("Pencil.cur");
        //this.Cursor = drawCursor;


    }


    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        //Cursor.Position = new Point(this.Location.X - this.Width / 2, this.Location.Y - this.Height / 2)
        UserControl1 userc1 = new UserControl1();
        userc1.Show();
        brushsize = Convert.ToInt16(label1.Text);


    }

    private void rectangleShape1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void Test_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //testing 
        //Console.WriteLine("X:" + mousex);
        //onsole.WriteLine("Y: " + mousey);
    }

    private void Form1_SizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }


    public void Form1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs i)
    {

            drawcount = drawcount + 1;
            System.Drawing.SolidBrush myBrush = new System.Drawing.SolidBrush(System.Drawing.Color.Red);
            System.Drawing.Graphics formGraphics;
            formGraphics = this.CreateGraphics();
            formGraphics.FillRectangle(myBrush, new Rectangle(i.X, i.Y, brushsize, brushsize));
            myBrush.Dispose();
            formGraphics.Dispose();
            count.Text = Convert.ToString(drawcount);


    }

    private void Paint_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        //this method will be used later when page resizing is added to the program.

        //Graphics g = e.Graphics;
        //Control control = (Control)sender;
        //drawPoint = control.PointToScreen(new Point(MousePosition.X, MousePosition.Y));
        //g.DrawRectangle(System.Drawing.Pens.Red, drawPoint.X, drawPoint.Y, 1, 1);

    }

    private void newToolStripButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //SetupDoc newsetup = new SetupDoc();
        //newsetup.ShowDialog();
    }

    private void PaintImg_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void panel1_Click(object sender, MouseEventArgs i)
    {
        drawcount = drawcount + 1;
        recordpoint = new Point(i.X, i.Y);
        pts.Add(recordpoint);
        System.Drawing.SolidBrush myBrush = new System.Drawing.SolidBrush(System.Drawing.Color.Red);
        System.Drawing.Graphics formGraphics;
        formGraphics = this.CreateGraphics();
        formGraphics.FillRectangle(myBrush, new Rectangle(i.X, i.Y, brushsize, brushsize));
        myBrush.Dispose();
        formGraphics.Dispose();
        count.Text = Convert.ToString(drawcount);
    }

    private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        brushsize = brushsize + 1;
        label1.Text = Convert.ToString(brushsize);
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        brushsize = brushsize - 1;
        label1.Text = Convert.ToString(brushsize);
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Image bmp = new Bitmap(this.Width - panel1.Width, this.Height - panel1.Height);
        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
        {
            foreach (var recordpoint in pts)
            {

                g.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.Red), new Rectangle(Convert.ToInt16(recordpoint.X), Convert.ToInt16(recordpoint.Y), brushsize, brushsize));
            }
        }
        bmp.Save("testing.bmp");
    }

}
}
```

If anyone knows what I am doing wrong please tell mee!!!

Comment: Debug your code and determine weather or not pts is populated.

Answer (score 0):

`panel1_Click` records the coordinates in your `pts` collection, but the `Form1_MouseClick` event does not do this.  Both methods do draw the points, though.

Are you sure you are adding to the `pts` collection where you are expecting?

Comment: oh the Panel1_Click is a mistake I must have forgoten to remove it, but when I move the part that adds the posistion to the list into Form1_MouseClick it still doesn't work?.

Answer (score 0):

Check for the bitmap size

```
this.Width - panel1.Width,this.Height - panel1.Height
```

Comment: no that is correct - I needed the bitmap to be the size of the area that the user can draw so I got the height and width of the form and minused the height and width of panel1 (a control in the form) so that it is the same size as the amount of space the person has in the appication.

Comment: I meant check is height or width coming to zero.